# Type (key: String, value: Any) has no subscript members

Tags: swift, dictionary

I know this question has been asked before on SO, and I understood the explanation given in some of them and the solution. In fact the solutions I found was what I was doing prior to searching SO. But I am still getting an error. I have a dictionary that I set up like so:

```
var dictBarData = [String: Any]()
```

and then I populate it like so:

```
let vThisBar = UIView()

//set initial coordinates for view
var barX = 0.0
let barY = Double(vBarChart.frame.size.height - 40.0)
let barW = 60.0
var barH = 10.0

barX = getBarX(barIndex)

vThisBar.frame = CGRect(x:barX, y:barY, width:barW, height:barH)
vThisBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
vBarChart.addSubview(vThisBar);

var dictThisBar = [String: Any]()
dictThisBar["category"] = category
dictThisBar["value"] = value
dictThisBar["view"] = vThisBar
dictBarData[String(barIndex)] = dictThisBar
```

then I try to access these dictionaries like so:

```
for dictThisBar in dictBarData as Dictionary {
    print(dictThisBar["view"] as! UIView)
}
```

it's at this point I am getting the error (on the print). I'm making the transition from Objective-c to Swift (and am probably in the minority of liking Objective-C more :D), so I assume I have missed a step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **array** enumeration syntax for a **dictionary**, you need this

```
for (key, value) in dictBarData {
    print(key, value)
}
```

or

```
for (key, value) in dictBarData {
    if key == "view" { print(value as! UIView) }
}
```

or if you want to get only one value forget the loop:

```
print(dictThisBar["view"] as! UIView)
```

Since `dictBarData` is declared as `[String: Any]` there is no type cast needed.

Comment: Thanks, the hardest part of the transition is in my head I am still thinking in objective-c. :D

Answer (score 1):

To extend on @vadian, should you still want to use the array enumeration, you may still access the dictionary components as shown below

```
for dictThisBar in dictBarData as Dictionary 
{
    print(dictThisBar.key)
    print(dictThisBar.value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave vadian the win but you get a bump. :)